# How to Add Html Elements in Html Report

Tags: c#, html, console

I have one Application were we write output to Html file. For writing the text we use

```
Console.write("Added to Report");
```

Now I want to add a image so I use something like this.

```
string imageTag = "<img src=\"Winter.jpeg\" />";
Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(imageTag));
```

But in my html report it shows something like this :

```
&lt;img src="winter.jpeg" /&gt;
```

So the image is not added to the report and we just see the string.

Is there any way that I can add this in the report

```
string imagePath = string.Format(@"{0}\Resources\DashboardScreenshot\{1}.png", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, imageName);
            bmpCrop.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Png);
            string imageTag = String.Format("<img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"{1}\" />",imagePath, imageName);
            Console.Write(imageTag);
```

Comment: where i have to set ?

Comment: perhaps [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.contenttype.parameters(v=vs.100).Aspx) can help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `HtmlDecode` here. Because your tag has nothing to be decoded.

Use it when you are writing something which is an `escape sequence` in C#, or anything which will not be considered as text in C# only then you should use it.

Here is my testing:

```
string imageName = "img.jpg";
string imagePath = @"C:\xxxx\xxxxxxxx\Downloads\img.jpg";
string imageTag = String.Format("<img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"{1}\" />", imagePath, imageName);
Console.Write(imageTag);

File.WriteAllText("file.html", imageTag);
```

and its fine, I have the image on the browser.

Comment: Yes agreed to this. But is there any way to add that in the html report ?

Comment: Add it without decoding

Comment: What is the output? Doesn't it show the `image` you defined or is it not even interpreting the `image tag`?

Comment: Can you share the code that how are you writing it to the file?

Comment: I think you have the `image format` problem. Try `jpg` instead of `jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are HTML-**encoding** your content somewhere¹ outside the blocks of code you have shown us before it is written to the HTML file.

That won't work. If you want to add literal HTML tags to your HTML file, you must *not* HtmlEncode them.² Instead, only encode the "text parts", i.e., the parts which do not contain HTML tags:

```
Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.HtmlEncode("Added to Report. Note that 3 < 5."));
Console.WriteLine("<img src=\"Winter.jpeg\" />");
```

---

¹ My guess would be that the same block of code that insert the `<pre>` (cf. your comment to Shaharyar's answer) also does the (unintended) HTML encoding. If you are still unclear on how to solve this, show us this part of your code.

² ...and no, `Encode(Decode(someText)) != someText` (in general), so the workaround of decoding it first -- as you have tried -- won't work.

Comment: The code that I have shown is the only code that I am writing. Actually I am running a XUNIT framework and when the test gets completed I get the output in the html format. Now if I want to get the text I write console.write but now when the case runs I want to add the image as well in the report.

Comment: @Moiz: That explains it: xUnit probably takes the Console output, HtmlEncodes it and puts it in the report. Unless you can tweak xUnit not to HtmlEncode the Console output, I guess you are out of luck.

Comment: Thanks Heinzi, There is one xslt file of XUNIT which creates the tags. Can I twick that ?